# SSIS: Can't save "parallel load" option in Oracle destination with Attunity driver, how to solve this?

Tags: oracle, ssis, etl, parallelism

I am working on an existing SSIS package that has proven to run successfully, however, due to data volume issues, I would like to try enabling the "parallel load" option by selecting the tickbox in the "Oracle Destination component by Attunity" in the data flow task.

When I hit the 'ok' button to save this change, I get an error stating:

```
Error at ZZZZZ [Connection manager "XXXX"]: OCI error encountered. ORA-12170: TNS:Connect timeout occurred

Error at DFT - ZZZZZ [YYYYY NNNNNNN [2]]: The AcquireConnection method call to the connection manager XXXX failed with error code 0x80004005.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the AcquireConnection method call failed.
```

I should add that "Delay Validation" is set to "true" so I don't understand what it is trying to check in the background.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Guessing as I don't Oracle.

SSIS is a metadata driven technology. During development and execution, SSIS will attempt to compare known metadata state to the currently available.  Delay Validation is a signal to the execution engine that it should not validate the state of a data flow until the component receives the signal to run. This allows precursor/set-up tasks to ready the environment.

In the design experience, pretty much *any* change to the data flow will result in a call to a method named something like ReinitializeMetaData() The Delay Validation property here allows you to open the package and look at a data flow without the validation logic firing. However editing a package via the designer is going to result in a metadata check.

So, if the designer causes a validation check and something with your machine doesn't support the Oracle connection validating itself, your options are to either:  figure out the connection issue - common culprits are wrong credentials, drivers not installed or 32 vs 64 compatibility, and tnsnames.ora not set up correctly

The other option and it's not one I suggest lightly, is edit the package with a text editor.

1. Ensure you're using source control.
2. Open file and scan through the XML looking for your destination name
3. Poke around and hopefully there is a property/element listed that sounds like "parallel load"
4. Open the project in Visual Studio - is the Parallel Load checked (and have no new errors/warnings shown up)? If so, commit to source control. Otherwise roll back to previous version and try again.

Comment: Now realise after playing around that it seems like trying to save ANY change results in a timeout issue so I don't think this relates just to 'parallel load' and seems to be timeout related more generally - but only on this oracle connection.